# How to do random image block in Drupal 6 if I am using Fast Gallery module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a gallery created with Fast Gallery module. How I can do block where will 1 random  image from this gallery?

Comment: didn't get what you mean by "How I can do block where will 1 random image from this gallery?" can you make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that displays only 1 image. Then in the sort criteria, select Global: Random

Mike